# How to select columns not in GROUP BY clause or aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT cola, count(cola) over() as num, colb, colc
FROM public."tabA"
GROUP BY cola
```

When executed Spark SQL gives:

> ERROR: column "tabA.colb" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

How to select the count of a column along with other columns?

Comment: Since you are using window function count, you can lose the `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by explaining why you can't have `colb` when it's not part of a `groupBy` or aggregate function.

Just imagine what would happen if you had two records in a dataset with different `colb` for the same `cola`? What would be the value of `colb`?

```
val inventory = Seq(
  ("a", "__1__", "c"),
  ("a", "__2__", "c")).toDF("cola", "colb", "colc")

scala> inventory.show
+----+-----+----+
|cola| colb|colc|
+----+-----+----+
|   a|__1__|   c|
|   a|__2__|   c|
+----+-----+----+
```

### Using Windows

A possible solution is to use...window operators. As a matter of fact, you were very close to have used them with `over` function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byCola = Window.partitionBy("cola")

scala> inventory.withColumn("count", count("*") over byCola).show
+----+-----+----+-----+
|cola| colb|colc|count|
+----+-----+----+-----+
|   a|__1__|   c|    2|
|   a|__2__|   c|    2|
+----+-----+----+-----+
```

In SQL it'd be as follows:

```
inventory.createOrReplaceTempView("inventory")

scala> sql("""
     |   SELECT cola, count(cola) over byCola as num, colb, colc
     |   FROM inventory
     |   WINDOW byCola AS (PARTITION BY cola)
     | """).show
+----+---+-----+----+
|cola|num| colb|colc|
+----+---+-----+----+
|   a|  2|__1__|   c|
|   a|  2|__2__|   c|
+----+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you! The SQL worked great. I also tried using the withColumn one directly but couldn't infer the java syntax..                                                                           WindowSpec byCola = Window.partitionBy(cola);
inputtabDS.withColumn("count",inputtabDS.count(*) over byCola).show();

Comment: Thank you! The SQL worked great. I will spend sometime on Window functions usage..Thanks.. I also tried using the withColumn one directly but couldn't infer the java syntax..                                                                           WindowSpec byCola = Window.partitionBy(inputtabDS.apply(cola));
inputtabDS.withColumn("count",inputtabDS.count(*) over byCola).show();  this gave compilation issue complaining that The method count() in the type Dataset<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (WindowSpec)

Comment: Don't you have to put `*` in quotes like `"*"`?