# Spark SQL returning expression is neither present in the group by

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT
        COUNT(*) number,
        COALESCE(Presents, 0) Presents,
        f_date date_formated,
        CASE 
            WHEN (REPLACE(t.name, '.', '') LIKE '%TEST1%') THEN 'TEST1' 
            WHEN (REPLACE(t.name, '.', '') LIKE '%TEST2%') THEN 'TEST2' 
            ELSE 'UINT' 
        END Area,
        CASE 
            WHEN (t.cod= 1) THEN 'A' 
            WHEN (t.cod= 2) THEN 'B' 
            WHEN (t.cod= 3) THEN 'C' 
            WHEN (t.cod= 4) THEN 'E' 
            ELSE 'N/A' 
        END Code
     FROM
       TABLE t
     GROUP BY
       Presents, 
       date_formated,
       Area,
       Code
```

When I run this query using Spark SQL I get the following error

```
expression 't.name' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first()
```

Why is this happening since I'm grouping by Code and Area?

Comment: your query aggregate the columns but there is no aggregation expression for t.name, t.cod.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. But I have the same query on athena (with little changes) and works fine in Athena. Is this something spark sql specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html) requires all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT statement to be included in the GROUP BY**.

You can resolve this error by adding `t.name` and `t.cod` to the GROUP BY.

OR

using it inside an aggregate function.

Here is a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700933/how-to-select-columns-not-in-group-by-clause-or-aggregate-function).